# Returning values from Get function of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to get a return value from a get function from a jquery Get request on success.

I have tried many ways already but with no success. Two forms which i have tries are:

1)

```
GetResultOutput = function () {
    var outPut = "No Data Found";
    var test = test();
    return test["outPut"];
}

test = function()
{
    outPut = "No Data Found";
    **return** $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceUrl,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
                    outPut = "done";
        }
    });
}
```

2)

```
GetResultOutput = function () {
    outPut = "No Data Found";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceUrl,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            outPut = "done";
        }
    });
    return outPut;
}
```

But both of them is not giving me any result..

2nd one outputs me as no data found. and 1st one which is preferred one when googled...results as undefined

Comment: If you want this call synchronous, then AJAX is the wrong tool for the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also make your ajax call synchronous by using:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceUrl,
        async: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            outPut = "done";
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can, but it makes the browser lockup while its doing the request - kinda negates the purpose of ajax in the first place.

Comment: thats true..it may happen...so u recommend the below fn u provided..because that way when i tried i was getting errors

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get the output and then process it like:

```
var output = GetResultOutput();
process(output);
```

You could pass process as a callback like:

```
var GetResultOutput = function (callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceUrl,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            callback(xml);
        }
    });
};

// usage:
GetResultOutput(process);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax request are asynchronous, which means you cannot immediately "return" data from the call. That is why all forms of `$.ajax` take one or more callbacks to be called when data is received, or an error occurs etc.

Which means your method must look like:

```
GetResultOutput = function (callback) {
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceUrl,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: callback
    });
}
```

with callback looking like:

```
function callback(xml)
{
   console.log('done: ' + xml);
}
```

Comment: tnx Jamiec, i better used making it async